# Creating PPT in C++ /cli

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I am trying to write the C++/cli equivalent of this C#:

```
// Create a PowerPoint application object.
PowerPoint.Application appPPT = new PowerPoint.Application();

// Create a new PowerPoint presentation.
PowerPoint.Presentation pptPreso = appPPT.Presentations.Add();
```

I have the first line:

```
ppt::Application^ PPT = gcnew ppt::ApplicationClass();
```

but I have not figured out how to do the second part, can someone please tell me how I would add a new PowerPoint Presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PowerPoint::Presentation ^pptPreso = appPPT->Presentations->Add();
```